Jena-Fuseki: Set per-query execution context
Using Jena-Fuseki v-5.1.0: I want to set the execution context of a query, but don't know how to do it. I need to set QuerySendMode to asPostForm.
Following this url guidelines, I've created a PREFIX arq (PREFIX arq: http://jena.apache.org/ARQ#), but I'm stuck. I've tried to do the following code, but it doesn't return anything.
SELECT DISTINCT ?x  WHERE { ?x  arq:httpServiceSendMode 'asPostForm'   }
Any ideas?
P.S.: I need to set QuerySendMode to asPostForm, because when doing a sparql federated query to nobelprize, it returns a text instead of the results and I'm thinking that it is because the endpoint returns a form ( see this question

The endpoint for nobelprize accepts GET.
curl --data-urlencode 'query=SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o } LIMIT 1' 'https://data.nobelprize.org/store/sparql' works
If you want to change the mode, that is done as a server configuration setting.
Set arq:httpServiceSendMode to asPostForm.
This is set by:

Command line starting the server: --set
Configuration file on the server or endpoint or (local) dataset.

